# Drag & Drop --> how to get div's className where element is dropped

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Drag-Drop (Getting element being dropped into)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447393/jquery-drag-drop-getting-element-being-dropped-into)

I am making a battleship and i defining the strategy. The idea is that user drag & drop the ships. My code looks like this.

### MY HTML

```
    <div id="strategyBoard" class="board">
    <h2>Define your Strategy</h2>

    <div>

        <div class="boardHeader"></div>
        <div class="boardHeader">A</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">B</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">C</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">D</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">E</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">F</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">G</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">H</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">I</div>
        <div class="boardHeader">J</div>
    </div>

    <div>

        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">1</div>
            <div class="1A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="1J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">2</div>
            <div class="2A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="2J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">3</div>
            <div class="3A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="3J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">4</div>
            <div class="4A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="4J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">5</div>
            <div class="5A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="5J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="sideHeader">6</div>
            <div class="6A boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6B boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6C boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6D boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6E boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6F boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6G boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6H boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6I boardBody"></div>
            <div class="6J boardBody"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="shipsBoard"> The Boats
  <div class="Ship"> <p>Destroyer: </p>
        <div><img src="/assets/images/ships/destroyer.png"  id="destroyer" width="70px" height="35px"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Ship"> <p>Patrol Ship: </p>
        <div><img src="/assets/images/ships/patrolShip.png"  id="patrolShip" width="70px" height="35px"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Ship"> <p>Aircraft Carrier: </p>
        <div><img src="/assets/images/ships/aircraftCarrier.png"  id="aircraftCarrier" width="175px" height="35px"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Ship"> <p>Battleship: </p>
        <div><img src="/assets/images/ships/battleship.png"  id="battleship" width="140px" height="35px"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Ship"> <p>Submarine: </p>
        <div><img src="/assets/images/ships/submarine.png" id="submarine" width="105px" height="35px"/></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### MY JS

```
  var value = 0;
  $( "#aircraftCarrier, #battleship, #destroyer, #patrolShip, #submarine" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid"});
  $("#aircraftCarrier, #submarine, #patrolShip, #destroyer, #battleship").rotate({
     bind:
       {
             click: function(){
           value +=90;
           $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})

             }
       }

  });


  $( "#strategyBoard .boardBody" ).droppable({

     drop: function(event, ui) {
      var position=event.target.className;
      alert(position);
      },
       hoverClass: "hoverClass"
  });
```

### MY CSS

I am using less

```
   /* ===== Board Game CSS ========================================================
      Author: Team n&n
      ========================================================================== */

   #strategyRoom{
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 768px;
     background: url("/assets/images/batallaNaval.jpg");
     background-position:50% 50%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     font-size: 16px;
   }

   #strategyBoard {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 50px;
   }

   .shipsBoard {
     color: black;
     float: right;
     padding: 40px;
     background-color: gray;
     .Border-radius;
     margin: 50px;

   }

   .hoverClass{
       opacity: 0.4;
   }
   .boardHeader {
       color: white;
    margin: 10px;
   }

   .sideHeader {
       width: 20px;
       padding: 0;
       color: white;
   }
```

My question is, how can i get ALL the class name where the div is dropped! The dropped element is an image that has the size of 2 o 3 o 4 o 5 div boardBody, depending of the ship. Actually, i've got only the classname where the mouse is pointing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I edit the question with my css, take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [JqueryUI's droppable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#default), is quite easy to use

Take a look at my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KnDmz/1/) .When a div is dragged and dropped in the target its' class is displayed in an alert box. Notice that due to plugin's functionality additional classes are added to your draggable div.

Comment: i am using that plugin, but $(ui.draggable).attr('class') is not working for me, that's why i put event.target.className

Comment: with $(ui.draggable).attr('class'), I'm getting the class of the draggable, but what i need is the class of the doppable!

Comment: This is even more easy, getting the droppable's class, try this snippet
`$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var myClass=$( this ).attr('class');
    alert(myClass); 
   }
  });`

As I mentioned above the class of both droppable and draggable objects are still quite a mess, I will suggest

Comment: yes i know, but there i obteined the place where the mouse drop the div, but not all the divs!! A element that is drag y dropped into many droppable divs y want to get all the divs!